# How can I check at runtime whether a class's fields are allowed to be null/undefined, to validate JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Let's say I've got an object like this:

```
class MyObject {
    requiredString: string,
    nullableString: string | undefined
}
```

and I want to be able to deserialize JSON into this object while enforcing that it *has* the required string, but not enforcing that it has the nullable one.

So, all these tests should pass:

```
const validJson1 = '{"requiredString":"a needed value!","nullableString":"an unneeded value!"}'
const validJson2 = '{"requiredString":"whatever!"}'
const invalidJson = '{"nullableString":"I am the God Of Teeth!"}'

class MyObject {
    requiredString: string,
    nullableString: string | undefined
}

function myMagicValidator<T>( objectInstance:T ) {
    // Throws exception if objectInstance is not a valid <T>
}

test('works whatsoever', () => {
    let testObject = JSON.parse(validJson1)
    myMagicValidator<MyObject>(testObject)
})

test('respects optional values', () => {
    let testObject = JSON.parse(validJson2)
    myMagicValidator<MyObject>(testObject)
})

test('enforces required values', () => {
    let testObject = JSON.parse(invalidJson)
    expect(myMagicValidator<MyObject>(testObject)).toThrow()
})

// Ideally this could work too, but it's not strictly needed
const invalidJson2 = '{"requiredString":5,"nullableString":"another value!"}'
test('enforces type safety', () => {
    let testObject = JSON.parse(invalidJson2)
    expect(myMagicValidator<MyObject>(testObject)).toThrow()
})
```

But the *trick* is that I don't own the object, MyObject actually gets imported from another package and isn't modifiable in my code. The requirement is that if another field is added to MyObject that's required, **myMagicValidator should automatically start checking for it** when node_modules updates to include the new field.

Comment: The current top answer is correct. I suggest to use `io-ts` to perform such validations at runtime, especially if the shape to validate gets more complex than a single js check. See for instance my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56773079/11401030. The great thing about io-ts is that, no matter how complex the validation is, downstream you'll end up with static type guarantees if it is successful

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is inherently static. The types are stripped during compile-time and do not exist at runtime, so you can't check the object shape at runtime. For runtime checks, just use JS code.

```
function myMagicValidator<T>( objectInstance:T ) {
  if (!Reflect.has(objectInstance, 'requiredString')) {
    throw new Error('Missing requiredString');
  }
}
```

Note: depending on your need (and syntactic preferences), you can also use [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) or the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check for property existence.

Comment: The trouble is, how do I get that list of required strings at runtime?

Comment: You'd need to define a runtime type and validate against that yourself. There are many libs to use for this purpose, ine idea is something like proptypes in React, json-gate, etc